# Python - Download zip files with requests package but get unknown file format

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib, wget

I am using Python 3.8.12. I tried the following code to download files from URLs with the `requests` package, but got 'Unkown file format' message when opening the zip file. I tested on different zip URLs but the size of all zip files are 18KB and none of the files can be opened successfully.

```
import requests

file_url = 'https://www.censtatd.gov.
hk/en/EIndexbySubject.html?pcode=D5600091&scode=300&file=D5600091B2022MM11B.zip'
file_download = requests.get(file_url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True)
open(save_path+file_name, 'wb').write(file_download.content)
```

[Zip file opening error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wdAj.png)

[Zip files size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBTKV.png)

However, once I updated the url as `file_url = 'https://www.td.gov.hk/datagovhk_tis/mttd-csv/en/table41a_eng.csv'` the code worked well and the csv file could be downloaded perfectly.

I try to use `requests`, `urllib` , `wget` and `zipfile` `io` packages, but none of them work.

The reason may be that the zip URL directs to both the zip file and a web page, while the csv URL directs to the csv file only.

I am really new to this field, could anyone help on it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You might examine headers after sending [`HEAD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/methods/head) request to get information regarding file, examining [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) allows you to reveal actual type of file

```
import requests
file_url = 'https://www.censtatd.gov.hk/en/EIndexbySubject.html?pcode=D5600091&scode=300&file=D5600091B2022MM11B.zip'
r = requests.head(file_url)
print(r.headers["Content-Type"])
```

gives output

```
text/html
```

So file you have URL to is actually HTML page.

Answer (score -1):

```
import wget

url = 'https://www.censtatd.gov.hk/en/EIndexbySubject.html? 
pcode=D5600091&scode=300&file=D5600091B2022MM11B.zip'
#url = 'https://golang.org/dl/go1.17.3.windows-amd64.zip'
wget.download(url)
```